# How do i auto-decrement primary key value in SQlite Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, sqlite

I have a tables in android SQLite and I am trying to figure out how to reset the `KEY_ID`, I read that: `DELETE FROM tablename` should delete everything and reset the autoincremement field back to 0 but when I do this it just deletes the data. When a new record is inserted the autoincrement picks up where it left off before the delete. I have implemented a `longitemclicklistner` on list, it gets the position and i want to delete the particular item from the list.
Here is my code

```
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) } );


        db.close();
    }
```

Here is the code in `onlongclicklistner`

```
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                     int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.v("long clicked","pos"+" "+pos);

                final int p=pos+1;

                final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                b.setMessage("Are you sure you want to DELETE this Entry?");
                b.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                           // continue with delete

                            db.getWritableDatabase();
                            db.deleteContact(db.getContact(p));
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                });
                b.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                });

                b.show();

         }
```

The problem is, `id1` is created then `id2` is created but when i delete `id2` and create a new contact, it gets the `id3`. i want it to get `id2`

Comment: Instead of DELETE statement, use Truncate <table-name> this will remove your data and set autoincrement to 0 back.

Comment: @Vigbyor TRUNCATE is not available in sqlite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you need that? It'll make inserts extremely slow. Suppose you have data 1,2,3,4....700, and you deleted 2 what would you do? move all the numbers up? (re-insert)?

or you'll set the next insert index to 2? right then... now delete 18, 45, 70. And insert a new row. After inserting to 18... it has to search for 45? lets say you keep a track of all the empty spaces as well for now, even then how would you cater for removing in random order 205, 102, 300, 50

You can use heap for storing available indexes, but it makes no sense as well. Maybe if you have some specific use case and share that with us we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: I have a generic list, every time a new contact is created it is then added to the list, list will have at max, say 200 items. i am using the DELETE() function on the list, by getting the position of the list. the database entry on the pos+1 is delted from the database table.

Answer (score 5):

That's a feature of `AUTOINCREMENT`. To make the keys reused, change the column definition from

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

to just

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

Further reading: http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: I am using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, but still its doing the same thing, further more i have incremented the database version to, still no use

Comment: Might be that `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` field gets the value `MAX(id)+1` if not explicitly specified. If you've deleted something in the middle, its id doesn't get reused.